# NodeJS, Express, how to update client side to display uploaded file

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express, routes

I am a beginner when it comes to nodeJS, AJAX requests, and routing. I followed the tutorial here [nodejs, express example](https://coligo.io/building-ajax-file-uploader-with-node/), and everything is working server-side. I cannot for the life of me however figure out how to display the uploaded file (in this case an image) back to the client. When I make a request for the file which is located in a seperate /uploads/ directory I get a 404 response from the server. I am assuming this is a routing issue, but am confused about how to create the GET request in express for an uploaded file

## **app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');
var formidable = require('formidable');
var fs = require('fs');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));


//passport for login credentials
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy; //here we implement the strategy that passport uses

var crypto = require('crypto');
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3');

var db = new sqlite3.Database('users.sqlite3');
var check;
db.serialize(function() {

  db.run("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, username TEXT, password TEXT, salt TEXT)");
  console.log('user table created');
  db.run("DELETE FROM users");    //clear table on run for debug
  var stmt = db.prepare("INSERT INTO users VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
  stmt.run('15', 'tg', 'tg', "333");
  stmt.finalize();

  db.each("SELECT username, password, id, salt FROM users", function(err, row) {
      console.log(row.username + ": " + row.password + ": " + row.id + ': ' + row.salt);
  });
});

//db.close();


function hashPassword(password, salt) {
  console.log('password hashing');
  var hash = crypto.createHash('sha256');
  hash.update(password);
  hash.update(salt);
  return hash.digest('hex');
}

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done) {
  console.log('using local strat for passport');
  db.get('SELECT salt FROM users WHERE username = ?', username, function(err, row) {
    if (!row) return done(null, false);
    var hash = hashPassword(password, row.salt);
    console.log('done hashing');
    db.get('SELECT username, id FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?', username, hash, function(err, row) {
      if (!row){
        console.log('failure'); 
        return done(null, false);
      }
      console.log('success');
      return done(null, row);
    });
  });
}));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  console.log('serializing');
  return done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  console.log('deserializing')
  db.get('SELECT id, username FROM users WHERE id = ?', id, function(err, row) {
    if (!row) return done(null, false);
    return done(null, row);
  });
});

///end user authentication

//on access to site, serve the user the login page
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'views/home.html'));

});

//providing routing access for success/failure on login attempt
app.post('/login', 
  passport.authenticate('local', {  successRedirect: '/home',
                                    failureRedirect: '/fail' }));

app.get('/fail', function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'views/error.html'));
});

app.get('/home', function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'views/home.html'));
});

app.get('/login', function(req,res){
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'views/login.html'));
   console.log('login unsuccessful');
});

app.get('/home', function(request, response) {
        response.render('views/home');
});

app.get('/upload' , function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/uploads');
});

app.post('/upload', function(req, res){

  // create an incoming form object
  var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

  // specify that we want to allow the user to upload multiple files in a single request
  form.multiples = true;

  // store all uploads in the /uploads directory
  form.uploadDir = path.join(__dirname, '/uploads');

  // every time a file has been uploaded successfully,
  // rename it to it's orignal name
  form.on('file', function(field, file) {
    fs.rename(file.path, path.join(form.uploadDir, file.name));
  });

  // log any errors that occur
  form.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('An error has occured: \n' + err);
  });

  // once all the files have been uploaded, send a response to the client
  form.on('end', function() {
    res.end('success');
  });

  // parse the incoming request containing the form data
  form.parse(req);

});

var server = app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('Server listening on port 3000');
});
```

## upload.js

```
'use strict'

$('.upload-btn').on('click', function (){
    $('#upload-input').click();
    $('.progress-bar').text('0%');
    $('.progress-bar').width('0%');
});

$('#upload-input').on('change', function(){

  var files = $(this).get(0).files;

  if (files.length > 0){
    // create a FormData object which will be sent as the data payload in the
    // AJAX request
    var formData = new FormData();

    // loop through all the selected files and add them to the formData object
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      var file = files[i];

      // add the files to formData object for the data payload
      formData.append('uploads[]', file, file.name);
    }

    $.ajax({
      url: '/upload',
      type: 'POST',
      data: formData,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      success: function(data){
        console.log('upload success');
      },
      xhr: function() {
        // create an XMLHttpRequest
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        // listen to the 'progress' event
        xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(evt) {

          if (evt.lengthComputable) {
            // calculate the percentage of upload completed
            var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
            percentComplete = parseInt(percentComplete * 100);

            // update the Bootstrap progress bar with the new percentage
            $('.progress-bar').text(percentComplete + '%');
            $('.progress-bar').width(percentComplete + '%');

            // once the upload reaches 100%, set the progress bar text to done
            if (percentComplete === 100) {
              $('.progress-bar').html('Done');
              console.log(formData);
              showUploadedItem(file.name);
            }


          }


        }, false);

        return xhr;
      }
    });

  }
});


function showUploadedItem (source) {
      var list = document.getElementById("image-list"),
      li   = document.createElement("li"),
      img  = document.createElement("img");
      img.src = source;
      li.appendChild(img);
      list.appendChild(li);
}
```

Comment: `File` object does not have a `.path` property by default.

Answer (score 0):

So after digging around for a while, I found that you have to explicitly request that express can server static files to the client side this is done by adding:

```
app.use(express.static('your_uploads_directory'));
```

Apparently everything else was set-up correctly per my and the tutorial's implementation.

Answer (score 0):

First of all when reading your post it seems like the file you want to download is placed in `/uploads` which is a folder in the root of your project. In the `app.js` file you provided at line 7 you have the following code.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

This line makes sure that all requests found that follow the folder structure in this public folder are caught and provided with the files in that folder, so for example when the public folder contains the following file: `/public/stylesheets/foo.css` all calls from the client to `/stylesheets/foo.css` will be caught and provided with this file.

More explanation can be found here [express documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html).

So for your file in the `/uploads` folder to work you could consider two options, place the file/folder in the `/public` folder or change your code to provide a static link to the files in the `/uploads` folder.

The first option is quite straight forward, the second option would require the following line.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'uploads')));
```

Keep in mind that the oder in which you place these lines matters, for example when you add this second line it means that all requests that follow the structure of the files in that folder will be caught and that file will be returned. Yet it also works the other way around, if you have an `app.use`, that has the exact same link as a file in one of these static links, which is placed before/above the static call the static call will not be reached. You can avoid this, for example when you want something to happen before the file is sent, since this is not related to the question I will provide a link to the so called [middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html).